# ImportError while importing test module

Tags: python, playwright

When I run my Playwright test, I get the following error:

```
ImportError while importing test module 'C:\Users\fsdam\OneDrive\Documents\python_work\playwright-python-tutorial\tests\test_search.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
C:\Users\fsdam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
test_search.py:2: in <module>
    from pages.search import DuckDuckGoSearchPage
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pages'
```

It complains that there is no module names `pages`. But `pages` is a package. I am following a tutorial and I do not see any difference in my code and folder structure when compared. Any help would be great.

Here is my folder structure:

```
.
└── playwright_python_tutorial  /
    ├── pages/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── result.py
    │   └── search.py
    └── tests/
        └── test_search.py
```

Here is my code that contains the test containing the imports:

```
from playwright.sync_api import expect, Page
from pages.search import DuckDuckGoSearchPage
from pages.result import DuckDuckGoResultPage

def test_basic_duckduckgo_search(page: Page) -> None:
    search_page = DuckDuckGoSearchPage(page)
    result_page = DuckDuckGoResultPage(page)

    #Given the DuckDuckGo home page is displayed
    search_page.load()

    #When the user searches for a phrase
    page.locator('id=searchbox_input').fill('panda')
    #page.fill('id=searchbox_input', 'panda')
    page.locator('xpath=//button[@aria-label="Search"]').click()

    #Then the search result query is the phrase
    expect(result_page.search_input).to_have_value('panda')
    # Alternative way:  assert 'panda' == page.input_value('id=search_form_input')

    #And the search result links pertain to the phrase
    assert result_page.result_link_titles_contain_phrase('panda')

    #And the search result title contains the phrase 
    expect(page).to_have_title('panda at DuckDuckGo')
```

Comment: Try `import sys; sys.path.insert(1, 'pages')` before the) `from pages...`  line. [[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383597)]. Let me know!

Comment: Thanks. This is what worked for me: import sys
sys.path.append('../')

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by adding:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40612922/843075)

Comment: This answer may be getting downvoted since using fiddling with `sys.path` is usually an unnecessary hack. It's generally preferable to have your package structure / Python path set up correctly from the start. In this case you seem to want `pages` to be a top-level package, so you should configure your environment so that `playwright_python_tutorial` is on he Python path before the interpreter even starts. That's usually done by installing your project as a distribution package or by relying on your CWD to be the top of your source directory

Comment: @Brian61354270  Thanks for your comment. Could you give me some guidance how to do this? I'm new to all this. When you say install I am used to installing external libraries, not my own.

Comment: You can check out the [official packaging guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/). Basically, just create a `pyproject.toml` file, add some configuration for your build system of choice (I'd recommend [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/)), then just `pip install -e .`. That will place your project's sources on the current interpreter's import path, making your packages importable from anywhere.